# What am I doing wrong in custom wordpress theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Ok I have my own `html/css` theme and I want to have it as a wordpress site but I have become stuck.

I have installed Wordpress on my GoDaddy account and put all the proper php files in the correct folder according to the tutorial video  http://example.com/wp-content/themes/example/  and I have made a `footer.php/header.php` and I have put

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

in the header and

```
  <?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

in the footer,

When I load up the site all it is showing is a very unstyled home page with just the header and footer, I then thought I probably have to call the header and footer on the index page somehow so I have

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

and

```
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I am uncertain where to put this so I put it on the index page at the top and at the bottom, but yeah it wont work.

any help would be nice cheers.

Comment: Documentation is your best friend. Read this. https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Comment: You need to bind any scripts and stylesheets through the functions.php page with [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) and `add_action` first, then they will be included in your header.

Answer (score 1):

As much I know about WP custom theme development, it's better to call wp_enque_script function inside your functions.php file and the add_action to init that script function.

Hope it works.